# Printing Selection from Firefox

Tags: firefox, printing

I often try to print some selected text from a webpage in Firefox (v.31 currently), but instead of printing nicely, it just prints some of the lines cut-off.  I end up having to copy the text, paste in Word and then print it.

Any ideas on how to get Firefox to print selected text correctly?

Comment: The problem is probably not Firefox but the web page and how it has been formatted.  You might try something like the Print Edit add-on (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-edit/), which may help force reformatting.

Answer (score 1):

We use some free pdf tools as my print option. Select the portion that you want to print and right click on the text, selected and choose Print option. This would create a pdf file and open it immediately you to print.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what tool do you use?